# Is it possible to open an error screen with a close button on top of a component?

Tags: react-native

I am designing a react native app. I have a bottom navigation with each one having their own components. 
So, when i click on edit a post, I make api calls, when the api returns an error i want to show an error page with a close button. The close button should basically close the error page and take me back to the edit component. (Something similar to a web view  which loads an url and has a close button. But, in my case i want to do a close button and show my error component. (Something like the red screen that react provides for on error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surely do that easily.

Step-1 : In the response code which you get from the API, if it is not 200(which is success) then save the error in a state.

Step -2 : Render a modal which will appear only when the error which is saved in state is not empty.

Step -3 : Put a close button there which will hide the modal.

Step- 4: Show the error content in the modal which you will get from the response of the API or some custom text which you want to show!